# Spring Boot Connection JPA Creation of Database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am setting up an app with Spring Boot. Each time I try to run it, it is blocked on the following line without an error message.

```
2021-06-05 10:19:01.706  INFO 16804 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
```

But when I make put a bad password for the database, it shows the error. I guess the problem is not with the database connection.

I try with MSSQL, PostGresSQL and MySQL, and Netbean Eclipse as well,  but it still stops in the line mentioned above.

Here is the elements of my Configuration:

- java version: java version "1.8.0_291"
- Spring Boot Version: 2.5.0
- Dependancies  are:
  Spring Web
  Spring Data JPA
  MS SQL Server Driver

Help me to understand where the problem is

[image]

Comment: This log output is expected for Spring 2.5.x.  What happens when you try to connect to your web application?

Comment: when i browse the web with "http://localhost:9040/, it loads normally. but the dabase is not generated. Which version of Spring should i use

Comment: And are there subsequent log messages?

Comment: I suggest trying `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`.  In addition, Spring Boot 2.5.x changed JPA initialization so you may need to set `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true` (see [Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes ](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql)).

Comment: Should the Repository need to be implemented before generating the database. Now, i just have the entity class

Comment: I don't think so but I also don't have any working examples where I haven't implemented at least one JpaRepository.  That said, I use `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` instead of `spring.datasource.driverClassName`.  I'm sorry I don't have a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi @AllenD.Ball , I add the interface and it works. is it normal?

Comment: It seems like it: Your original log shows no JPA repositories were scanned.